# Data parsing from a table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BeautifulSoup and I've been struggling with data parsing from a table:

```
<table id="data">
    <tr>
      <td class="random.data"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 0 -->
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 1 -->
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 2 -->
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 3 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=".random_data"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 0 -->
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 1 -->
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 2 -->
      <td class="values"></td> <!-- 3 -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a list of dictionaries like this pseudocode:

```
content = []
for tr in trs:
    info = {
        'name': tr.getChildren('.name').getText(),
        'value1': tr.getChildren('.values', 0).getText() # the first value from values
        'value3': tr.getChildren('.values', 3).getText() # the fourth value from values
    }
    content.append(info)
```

But I've been trying around and failing miserably to translate this into BeautifulSoup, any help or hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over table rows and, for ever row, find the `name` by the class name, all the values by the `values` class name and get the desired values by index:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<table id="data">
    <tr>
      <td class="random.data"></td>
      <td class="name">test1</td>
      <td class="values">0</td>
      <td class="values">1</td>
      <td class="values">2</td>
      <td class="values">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=".random_data"></td>
      <td class="name">test2</td>
      <td class="values">0</td> 
      <td class="values">1</td> 
      <td class="values">2</td> 
      <td class="values">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

data = []
for row in soup.select("table#data tr"):
    name = row.find("td", class_="name").get_text(strip=True)
    values = row.find_all("td", class_="values")

    data.append({
        "name": name,
        "value1": values[0].get_text(strip=True),
        "value3": values[3].get_text(strip=True)
    })

print data
```

Prints:

```
[
    {'value3': u'3', 'name': u'test1', 'value1': u'0'}, 
    {'value3': u'3', 'name': u'test2', 'value1': u'0'}
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the data isn't in the comments, that was my fault not putting some data there for the example. The comments were only to show the index and that I need only some of them like index 0 and 3.